# Como unir dos Arreglos? C++

Tags: c++, array

Soy nueva en esto, estoy tratanto de unir los dos arreglos a uno solo, pero no me sale.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     int cantidad1, cantidad2;
     int valor1, valor2;

     int arreglo1[cantidad1];
     int arreglo2[cantidad2];

     cout<<"Cuantos elementos tiene el primer arreglo? ";
     cin>>cantidad1;

     cout<<"Teclea los valores del primer arreglo: "<<endl;

     for(int i = 0; i< cantidad1; i++){

                cout<<(i+1)<<": ";
                cin>>valor1;
                arreglo1 [i]=valor1;
     }

    cout<<"Cuantos elementos tiene el segundo arreglo? ";
    cin>>cantidad2;

    cout<<"Teclea los valores del segundo arreglo: "<<endl;

          for(int j = 0; j<cantidad2; j++){

                cout<<(j+1)<<": ";
                cin>>valor2;
                arreglo2 [j]=valor2;
    }

    cout<<"A interseccion B: ";
    for (int i = 0; i<cantidad1; i++){
        for ( int j = 0; j<cantidad2; j++){
            if (arreglo1 [i]== arreglo2 [j]){

                cout<<arreglo1 [i]<<endl;               
                }
            }
        }       


        int arreglo3[10000];

        cout<<"A Union B: ";
        for (int i = 0; i<cantidad1; i++){
            arreglo3[i] = arreglo1 [i];
        for ( int j = 0; j<cantidad2; j++){
                arreglo3[i] = arreglo2 [j];

            for (int i = 0; i <cantidad1 + cantidad2; i++){
                cout<<arreglo3[i]<<endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;            
}
```

Comment: puedes poner el error que te dá y si usas alguna variante de c++ en particular ( por ejemplo gcc version mil ocho mil )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No uses *VLA***

Los arrays de longitud variable o *VLA* (Variable Length Array) no son una característica soportada por el estándar... que el *VLA* compile depende del compilador que uses y de las extensiones que tenga instaladas... hay soluciones mejores.

¿Qué es un *VLA*? Esto:

```
 int cantidad1, cantidad2;

 int arreglo1[cantidad1]; // <<--- VLA
 int arreglo2[cantidad2]; // <<--- VLA
```

Son *VLA* porque su tamaño viene dado por una variable en vez de por una constante.

Bueno, aparte del uso del *VLA* (que puede o no compilar), aquí tenemos un error más grave y es que `cantidad1` y `cantidad2` no están inicializadas... y dado que se usan estas variables para darle un tamaño a `arreglo1` y `arreglo2`... ¿qué tamaño van a tener estos arrays? ¿0? ¿un número negativo? ¿17 millones de elmentos cada uno? No lo sabes.

En contra de lo que pudieses pensar en un primer momento, esto no va a funcionar:

```
int numElementos;
int miArray[numElementos];

// Quiero almacenar 10 elementos
numElementos=10;
for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
  miArray[i] = /* ... */;

// Ahora quiero almacenar 20
numElementos=20;
for( int i=0; i<20; i++ )
  miArray[i] = /* ... */;
```

Si el número de elementos viene dado por el usuario puedes usar o memoria dinámica:

```
int cantidad1;

std::cin >> cantidad1;
int* arreglo1 = new int[cantidad1];

// ...

delete[] arreglo1;
```

> estoy tratanto de unir los dos arreglos a uno solo, pero no me sale.

Un error que tienes es que el segundo bucle abarca también la impresión del resultado... luego el mismo te va a salir más veces de las deseadas:

```
for ( int j = 0; j<cantidad2; j++){ // <<--- llave de apertura
        arreglo3[i] = arreglo2 [j];

    for (int i = 0; i <cantidad1 + cantidad2; i++){
        cout<<arreglo3[i]<<endl;
    }
} // <<--- llave de cierre
```

Tienes que limitar correctamente el alcance de cada bucle:

```
for ( int j = 0; j<cantidad2; j++){
    arreglo3[i] = arreglo2 [j];
}

for (int i = 0; i <cantidad1 + cantidad2; i++){
    cout<<arreglo3[i]<<endl;
}
```

Por otro lado, para unir los dos arreglos necesitas tres índices... uno por cada arreglo.

Copiar el primer arreglo es trivial y ya lo has hecho:

```
for (int i = 0; i<cantidad1; i++){
  arreglo3[i] = arreglo1 [i];
```

Pero para el segundo necesitas dos índices y necesitas actualizar ambos:

```
 for ( int i=cantidad1, j = 0; j<cantidad2; i++, j++)
   arreglo3[i] = arreglo2 [j];
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la forma en la que estas anidando los for porque en el segundo estas escribiendo los datos dentro del mismo indice, no se si lo que quieres hacer es mostrar la suma o si querías mostrar todos los datos de los dos arreglos en un solo arreglo

```
    for (int i = 0; i<cantidad1; i++){
        arreglo3[i] = arreglo1 [i];
        for ( int j = 0; j<cantidad2; j++){
            arreglo3[i] = arreglo2 [j];  // Aqui es donde sobre escribes
             for (int i = 0; i <cantidad1 + cantidad2; i++){ // se va a repetir la impresión porque esta dentro de tu ciclo principal y va a generar muchas impresiones basura, para imprimir cuando ya estén unidos tus arreglos saca este for  
            cout<<arreglo3[i]<<endl;
             } //For de impresión 
         } //Segundo For
     } //For principal
```

Esos serian lo problemas que yo creo que te ocasiona tu codigo

Si quisieras unir los datos de un arreglo y otro podrías usar algo asi:

```
    int cantidadTotal = cantidad1 + cantidad2;
    int contador = 0, contador2 = 0;
    while (cantidadTotal > contador) {
        if (contador>cantidad1-1) {
            arreglo3[contador] = arreglo2[contador2];
            contador2++;
        } else {
            arreglo3[contador] = arreglo1[contador];
        }
        contador++;
    }
```