# Concatenar vectores con std::vector en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, codeblocks, c++98

Quería saber como se podría concatenar dos arreglos en C++:

Por ejemplo

```
a = {1,2,3,4,5} 
b = {6,7,8,9,10}
c = a + b
//El resultado c = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue respondida anteriormente. Te recomiendo visitar: > https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156073/como-unir-dos-arreglos-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para concatenar esos dos arrays en un vector te bastan dos simples líneas de código:

```
std::vector<int> c(std::begin(a),std::end(a));
c.insert(c.end(),std::begin(b),std::end(b));
```

La primera crea el vector `c` y copia en el mismo el contenido del array `a`. La segunda simplemente añade al vector `c` el contenido del array `b`.

Si, por algun casual, quisieses hacerlo en otro array te toca recurrir al uso de memoria dinámica:

```
int size_a = std::distance(std::begin(a),std::end(a));
int size_b = std::distance(std::begin(b),std::end(b));
int* c = new int[size_a + size_b];

int* iter = std::copy(std::begin(a),std::end(a),c);
std::copy(std::begin(b),std::end(b),iter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen diversas formas de hacerlo aquí te dejo algunos ejemplos

Dados los vectores:

```
std::vector<int> A = {...};
std::vector<int> B = {...};
std::vector<int> AB;
```

1.- Copiar ambos vectores

```
//Así sólo se asigna la memoria necesaria una vez
AB.reserve(A.size() + B.size());
AB.insert(AB.end(), A.begin(), A.end());
AB.insert(AB.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
```

2.- Otra forma de copiar

```
AB.reserve(A.size() + B.size());
std::copy(A.begin(), A.end(), std::back_inserter(AB));
std::copy(B.begin(), B.end(), std::back_inserter(AB));
```

3.- Otra más

```
AB = A;
AB.reserve(AB.size() + B.size());
AB.insert(AB.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
```

4.- Por ultimo, si ya no vas a necesitar los vectores por separado puedes mover el vector A y evitar hacer la copia de este vector

```
AB = std::move(A);
AB.reserve(AB.size() + B.size());
AB.insert(AB.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
```

Como detalle final puedes sobrecargar el operador + y += si quieres utilizar la sintaxis que utilizas como ejemplo

5.-

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(const std::vector<T>& A, const std::vector<T>& B)
{
    std::vector<T> AB;
    AB.reserve( A.size() + B.size() );
    AB.insert( AB.end(), A.begin(), A.end() );        
    AB.insert( AB.end(), B.begin(), B.end() );        
    return AB;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& A, const std::vector<T>& B)
{
    A.reserve( A.size() + B.size() );                
    A.insert( A.end(), B.begin(), B.end() ); 
    return A;
}

int main(int, char**) {
  std::vector<int> A = {1,2,3};
  std::vector<int> B = {4,5,6};
  std::vector<int> AB = A + B;
  //o 
  std::vector<int> BA;
  BA += B;
  BA += A;
  return 0;
}
```